# Can't load .png image using opengl texture

Tags: opengl, graphics

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define KEY_ESCAPE 27

void display();
void keyboard(unsigned char,int,int);
GLuint LoadTextureRAW( const char * filename, int wrap );

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);                                    
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH );
    glutInitWindowSize(600,400);                  
    glutCreateWindow("Opengl Test");                              
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
void display() {
    GLuint texture=LoadTextureRAW("ball.png",1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(0.0,0.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(1.0,0.0);
    glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(1.0,1.0);
    glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(0.0,1.0);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();    
}
// load a 256x256 RGB .RAW file as a texture
GLuint LoadTextureRAW( const char * filename, int wrap )
{
    GLuint texture;
    int width, height;
//    BYTE * data;
    int *data;
    FILE * file;

    // open texture data
    file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    if ( file == NULL ) return 0;

    // allocate buffer
    width = 256;
    height = 256;
    data = (int*)malloc( width * height * 3 );

    // read texture data
    fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
    fclose( file );

    // allocate a texture name
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

    // select our current texture
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    // select modulate to mix texture with color for shading
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

    // when texture area is small, bilinear filter the closest mipmap
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                     GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
    // when texture area is large, bilinear filter the first mipmap
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    // if wrap is true, the texture wraps over at the edges (repeat)
    //       ... false, the texture ends at the edges (clamp)
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                     wrap ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                     wrap ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP );

    // build our texture mipmaps
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,
                       GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );

    // free buffer
    free( data );

    return texture;
}
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int mousePositionX, int mousePositionY) { 
    switch ( key ) {
        case KEY_ESCAPE:
            exit ( 0 );   
            break;      
        default:      
            break;
    }
}
```

I followed this, http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html

What should i do?

Comment: Is the size of your texture a power of 2?

Comment: I don't know, how would i know that?

Comment: The best way to learn this stuff is not to keep asking us questions every time some code you copy and pasted doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"LoadTextureRAW()" is not for PNG files. You will need a third party library like [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) to decode a png file, because they are compressed.

If you don't want to implement libpng yourself, which is kind of advanced, then you can probably find a wrapper library on google somewhere.

You can find a minimal implementation of libpng here:
http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html

Comment: No, for any image except .RAW, you will need some sort of decoder/parser. Even uncompressed images like targas and bmp files will have a header that contains, at the very least, the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Can you post that code to load png image? I have installed libpng with package manger on linux system.

Comment: `g++ n.cpp -o n` , erorr, `tex.cpp: In function ‘void read_png_file(char*)’:
tex.cpp:48: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘png_byte*’
tex.cpp:48: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int png_sig_cmp(png_byte*, png_size_t, png_size_t)’`

Comment: like I said, it's an advanced topic =)

Comment: @prime instead of using libpng give DevIl(http://openil.sourceforge.net/) a try. It is much easier to use and supports a variaty of image formats.